# Perform sequential api calls with RxJs?

Tags: rxjs

Is there a way in RxJs to perform two api calls where the second requires data from the first and return a combined result as a stream?  What I'm trying to do is call the facebook API to get a list of groups and the cover image in various sizes.  Facebook returns something like this:

```
// call to facebook /1234 to get the group 1234, cover object has an
// image in it, but only one size
{ id: '1234', cover: { id: '9999' } }

// call to facebook /9999 to get the image 9999 with an array
// with multiple sizes, omitted for simplicity
{ images: [ <image1>, <image2>, ... ] }

// desired result:
{ id: '1234', images: [ <image1>, <image2>, ... ] }
```

So I have this:

```
var result = undefined;
rxGroup = fbService.observe('/1234');
rxGroup.subscribe(group => {
  rxImage = fbService.observe(`/${group.cover.id}`);
  rxImage.subscribe(images => {
    group.images = y;
    result = group;
  }
}
```

I want to create a method that accepts a group id and returns an Observable that will have the combined group + images (result here) in the stream.  I know I can create my own observable and call the next() function in there where I set 'result' above, but I'm thinking there has to be an rx-way to do this.  [`select/map`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/select.md) lets me transform, but I don't know how to shoe-in the results from another call.  [`when/and/then`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/and.md) seems promising, but also doesn't look like it supports something like that.  I could `map` and return an observable, but the caller would then have to do two subscribes.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like flatMap is the way to go ([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/g5pj065m/5/)).  It is called like `subscribe` and gives you a value from a stream.  You return an observable from that and it outputs the values from all the created observables (one for for each element in the base stream) into the resulting stream.

```js
var sourceGroup = { // result of calling api /1234
  id: '1234',
  cover: {
    id: '9999'
  }
};
var sourceCover = { // result of calling api /9999
  id: '9999',
  images: [{
    src: 'image1x80.png'
  }, {
    src: 'image1x320.png'
  }]
};

var rxGroup = Rx.Observable.just(sourceGroup);
var rxCombined = rxGroup.flatMap(group =>
  Rx.Observable.just(sourceCover)
  .map(images => ({
    id: group.id,
    images: images.images
  }))
)

rxCombined.subscribe(x =>
  console.log(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.min.js"></script>
```

***Result***:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "images": [
    {
      "src": "image1x80.png"
    },
    {
      "src": "image1x320.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) instead of flatMap, it will preserve the order of the source emissions.